# C# Unit Test Project is missing in .NET framework v4 but present in v4.5.2

Tags: visual-studio, vs-unit-testing-framework

I can't seem to create a **Unit Test Project (.NET Framework Project)** that targets .NET Framework 4.0 (see Screenshot #1) but I can create one using .NET Framework 4.5.2 (see Screenshot #2). How do I create a **Unit Test Project (.NET Framework Project)** that targets .NET Framework 4.0?

**Screenshot #1**
[image]

**Screenshot #2**
[image]

Comment: I think 4.0 has been removed for security reasons. If you can't use the later framework I think your only option is to use an older version of VS, e.g. 2015. But it's recommended that you use the later framework.